# How can I advance in a copy of a linked list without changing the original

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list

So my question is, how can I advance in a copy of a linked list without changing the original list.
I kinda understand why this happens I just don't know a way to make it not happen.

This is what I've done and when I call another function that uses these lists they don't exist.

```
  typedef struct _edgeList
    {
        int target;
        char* tCity;
        char* country;
        int population;
        float weight;
        struct _edgeList *next;
    } EdgeList;

    typedef struct _collisionList
    {
        int id;
        char *city;
        char* country;
        int population;
        EdgeList *edges;
        struct _collisionList *next;
    } CollList;

    void CityWithMostTargets(CollList** hash)
{
    CollList** aux = hash;
    int i = 0;
    int edges = 0;
    int major = 0;
    char* city;

    for(i = 0; i < HASH_SIZE; i++)
    {
        while(aux[i])
        {
            if(aux[i]->edges)
            {
                edges = CountEdges(hash[i]->edges);
            }

            if(edges > major)
            {
                major = edges;
                city = strdup(hash[i]->city);
            }

            if(!aux[i]->next)
                break;

            aux[i] = aux[i]->next;
        }
    }
    aux = hash; 

    printf("City: %s\nNumber of edges: %d", city, major);
    getchar();
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "advance"?

Comment: @ScottHunter Hi Scott! By advance I mean,in that while when I do `aux[i] = aux->next`, when I advance in the aux, it also advances in the hash because when I use the hash variable in another function after this one it doesn't exist.

Comment: With the line 'aux = hash' you are making both aux and hash point to the same object in memory, you are not making a copy of 'hash'.  You will need to implement a deep-copy (i.e. copy the contents from 'hash' into a new linked list and manipulate that list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define another variable to hold the value of `aux[i]` that you want to work with.

```
for(i = 0; i < HASH_SIZE; i++)
{
    CollList* a = aux[i];
    while (a)
    {
        // etc.
```

and replace the other uses of `aux[i]` within that loop to use `a`.